# 配列の要素を順番通りに表示させたい

Tags: javascript, html

初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、以下のような場合に`div#b`が`div#a`の中に入ってしまいます。
それを解除して順番通りに表示するにはどうすればいいのか原因と対策を教えてください。
scriptがまとめて処理されるので順番通りに表示されないのでしょうか？

```
<div id="kihon14">
        <p>kihon14</p>
        <script>
            for (var i=1 ; i<=10 ; i++){
                document.write("繰り返し文ですYO！" + i + "<br>");
            }
        </script>
    </div>

    <div id="a">
        <p>配列との組み合わせ</p>
        <script>
            var rank = 1;
            var mnt = new Array(
                "富士山",
                "白根山",
                "奥穂高岳",
                "間ノ岳",
                "槍ヶ岳"
            );
            document.write('<table border="5">');
            for(var h = 0; h<=4; h++){
                document.write('<tr>');
                document.write('<td>'+rank+'位</td>');
                document.write('<td>'+mnt[h]+'</td>');
                document.write('</td>');
                rank++;
            }
        </script>
    </div>

    <div id="b">
        <p>continue + break</p>
        <script>
            for(var s=0; s<=10; s++){
                if(s == 3) continue;
                if(s == 7) break;
                document.write(s + "回目の繰り返しです。<br>");
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tableタグを閉じていないのでは？
付け足した所動作してるようです

```html
<div id="kihon14">
  <p>kihon14</p>
  <script>
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      document.write("繰り返し文ですYO！" + i + "<br>");
    }
  </script>
</div>

<div id="a">
  <p>配列との組み合わせ</p>
  <script>
    var rank = 1;
    var mnt = new Array(
      "富士山",
      "白根山",
      "奥穂高岳",
      "間ノ岳",
      "槍ヶ岳"
    );
    document.write('<table border="5">');
    for (var h = 0; h <= 4; h++) {
      document.write('<tr>');
      document.write('<td>' + rank + '位</td>');
      document.write('<td>' + mnt[h] + '</td>');
      document.write('</td>');
      rank++;
    }
    document.write('</table>');
  </script>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <p>continue + break</p>
  <script>
    for (var s = 0; s <= 10; s++) {
      if (s == 3) continue;
      if (s == 7) break;
      document.write(s + "回目の繰り返しです。<br>");
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: めちゃくちゃ初歩的なミスでお恥ずかしい限りです